# I am trying to search values in my vf page . thats why i am writing this code but error on CommandButton. Screen shot is attached

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Doctor__c" extensions="ItemEditController" showHeader="false">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!Doctor__c.Name}" subtitle="Edit Records" />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="block">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save Records" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel for="searchText">Keyword</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:panelGroup>
                        <apex:inputText id="searchText" value="{!searchText}" />
                        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" rerender="block" status="status" />
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection><br/>
            <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Searching... please wait..." />
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Results" id="resultsBlock" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!searchResults}" var="item" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(searchResults))}">
                    <apex:column value="{!item.Name}" headerValue="Item" width="100" />
                    <apex:column headerValue="Value" width="200">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!item.Contact_Area__c}" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!item.Speciality__c}" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!item.Qualification__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class ItemEditController {
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public List < Doctor__c > searchResults {get;set;}
    public string searchText {get;set;}
    // standard controller - could also just use custom controller
    public ItemEditController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}
    // fired when the search button is clicked
    public PageReference search() {
        String qry = 'select id, name, Contact_Area__c,Speciality__c,Qualification__c,Mobile_Number__c,Email__c from Doctor__c' +
            'where name LIKE \'%' + searchText + '%\'';
        searchResults = Database.query(qry);
        return null;
    }
    // fired when the save records button is clicked
    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            update searchResults;
        }
        Catch(DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
    }
    // takes user back to main record
    public PageReference cancel() {
        return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space is missing before `where` clause. Update the Query by adding a space as below. This will solve unexpected token issue.

```
public PageReference search() {
    String qry = 'select id, name, Contact_Area__c,Speciality__c,Qualification__c,Mobile_Number__c,Email__c from Doctor__c' +
        ' where name LIKE \'%' + searchText + '%\'';
    searchResults = Database.query(qry);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @bingi If my answer helps you, please mark it as answer. So that it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Query like this in your String

```
'select id, name, Contact_Area__c, Speciality__c, Qualification__c, Mobile_Number__c, Email__c from Account where name LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\''
```

Hope this might helps...